# How to get a root shell by using syslinux start parameter

Tags: startup, syslinux

I'm trying to get a root shell using the start parameter of syslinux. The Linux system runs directly into a kiosk mode and all keyboard entry is blocked.

Here is the original config:

```
label vegas
kernel vmlinuz
append acpi=off elevator=deadline initrd=initrd ram=/dev/ram0 root=/dev/ram0 init=/linuxrc vga=788 splash=silent
```

I already tried to use `init=/bin/sh` but then it says image not found.

Comment: Can you mount this system's filesystem in something else to explore what's actually on it. The executable `/bin/sh` may not be located where you think, might be called something else? If this is a kiosk, I'd expect it to have gone through some types of hardening as to limit ppl from doing what you're attempting. As it stands it sounds a little sketching what you're attempting to do here. Is this some sort of slot machine or something to do with gambling?

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunatly i can not see the files, i will try to find another solution if this does not work, and yes i am trying to get the gambling mashine back to life for private use, the license got deleted and i want to bypass the checking of it, it is my own mashine i bought on a site like craigslist. here is some more info:https://www.automatenfreunde.de/index.php?page=Thread&postID=38366&highlight=#post38366

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. Sounded suspicious on the surface, but makes more sense now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found the solution and it is as stupid as it gets.

i had to use `init=/bin/bash`.